# Problem with modify img source in markdown content with VueShowdown

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, markdown

I have a problem with my markdown content. i have to change img src. the src is an id who is sent by the backend, i need to make a get request with this id to get my image. To make this, i have a block of Js code which change the original src of each img.

```js
let course = document.getElementById("Course")
    let img = course.getElementsByTagName("img")
    for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
      img[i].src = `${this.$store.state.settings.API_URL}api/Images/${img[i].getAttribute('src')}`
      img[i].setAttribute("loading", "lazy")
      return img[i]
    }
```

The Course is the content of markdown.
The weird thing is that this code changes the source of the image well, if I log img[i].src in the loop, the result is as expected, in the html, it doesn't move.

Do you know why ?. Thank's you all !

Comment: The `return img[i]` will interrupt your loop upon its first iteration, so only the first image's src will be modified.

Comment: ah yes , right thanks